# Is it possible to have Ironman enabled by default?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I prefer to play the game in Ironman mode, but I need to enable it every time I start a new game. On the off chance I forget to do this I either need to continue playing with it turned off, or restart my game.

Is there anyways to have Ironman enabled by default? Alternatively, if there is a way to enable Ironman after the game has started that would work as well.

Comment: In the pause menu (on 360, at least) there is a "Change Difficulty" option. I haven't checked, but you might be able to enable Ironman mode there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you start a new game, it's not possible to change the Ironman setting (from off to on, or on to off), unlike the difficulty.

I know of no way to enable Ironman by default; I did a search of the config files on the PC version and couldn't find any setting within them that seemed to be Ironman related.

Comment: Yeah, I've looked through the config files myself and I haven't had any luck. Do you know where the save files are located? (Steam version)

Comment: @Wipqozn They're in %My Games%\XCOM - Enemy Unknown\XComGame\SaveData on Win 7.  Not in the steam folder.